# Nightmarejs code stuck with evaluate/then

Tags: node.js, nightmare

Based on the example from the github [page](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) I wrote the following code:

```
// There is some stuff before this that loads the page and do a few clicks but it's not relative to the problem

var selector = 'ContentPlaceHolder1_dtlA_lnkB_0';
nightmare
  .evaluate(function (selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector).innerText;
   }, selector)
  .then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
  })
```

However, when I run the code it gets stuck with no output. The browser doesn't even appear.

```
DEBUG=nightmare node checkjobs.js    
nightmare queuing process start +0ms
nightmare queueing action "goto" for http://xxxxxxxxx/Login.aspx +3ms
nightmare queueing action "type" +2ms
nightmare queueing action "type" +0ms
nightmare queueing action "click" +0ms
nightmare queueing action "wait" +0ms
nightmare queueing action "click" +0ms
nightmare queueing action "wait" +0ms
nightmare queueing action "click" +0ms
nightmare queueing action "evaluate" +0ms
nightmare running +1ms
nightmare running +16ms
```

However, if I comment the .then section. The rest of the code goes fine and the browser appears and does all the steps.

HTML looks like this:

```
<a id="CContentPlaceHolder1_dtlA_lnkB_0" class="LinkButonDark" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dtlA$ctl00$lnkB','')" style="color: #97c1e2; text-transform: capitalize;"><b>SOME TEXT I NEED TO CAPTURE</b></a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their example I always see [.end()](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#end) before `.then()`.

Try this:

```
var selector = 'ContentPlaceHolder1_dtlA_lnkB_0';
nightmare
  .evaluate(function (selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector).innerText;
   }, selector)
  .end()
  .then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
  })
```